# Reset password using SMS service instead of Email in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, single-page-application, asp.net-core-identity

I want to make an Api endpoint to send password reset token via SMS.

When we use `userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user)` to generate a token, the token is a long string that is usually used in an Email message. This message embeds a link containing the token as parameter and is sent to user. User clicks the link and then can change password.

Now, I have this question:

- How can I use SMS service instead of Email to send this token?
- Is that right and recommended way that I use the same token created using `UserManagerGeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(...)` in SMS or is better to use another token provider to generate a short 6-digit-like string?

Comment: If you are sending your verification message via SMS, you'll need to take into account, that the receiving devices may not be capable of accessing the internet, because it might not be a smartphone. In that case it may not be possible to click on a link or copy the verification code into a browser. Therefore I would recommend using a short reset code, which can easily be typed in manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync`, `GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync` and similar methods are using `GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, provider, purpose)` with specified provider and purpose under the hood.

We can use `GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, provider, purpose)` to generate a token the way we want. So this would be my endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost("sendResetPasswordToken")]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(ModelValidationFilter))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendChangePasswordToken([FromBody] SendChangePasswordTokenDto dto)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(dto.UserName);
        if (user is null)
            return UnprocessableEntity("something went wrong, contact support to resolve the problem");


        var token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultPhoneProvider, "ResetPasswordPurpose");
        _SMSManager.SendResetPasswordToken(token, user.PhoneNumber);
        return NoContent();
    }
```

We set provider param to `TokenOptions.DefaultPhoneProvider` that is a default phone token provider and set purpose param to `"ResetPasswordPurpose"` that is an string indicating the purpose of the token.

To verify this token we use `VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, provider, purpose, token)` and provide proper params. So here is my ResetPassword endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost("resetPassword")]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(ModelValidationFilter))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword([FromBody] ResetPasswordDto dto)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(dto.SSN);

        if(user is null)
            return UnprocessableEntity("invalid user token");//actually user not found

        var tokenVerified = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultPhoneProvider, "ResetPasswordPurpose", dto.Token);
        if (!tokenVerified)
            return UnprocessableEntity("invalid user token");

        var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);//new token for reseting password
        var result = await  _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, dto.NewPassword);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
            return UnprocessableEntity("weak password");

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, To reset users' passwords, you can verify users by sending a confirmation 6-digit string.

for this scenario, you would follow the below :

1. Create an endpoint to reset a password via SMS( in this action you should generate 6-digit strings and set the value into a cache(Redis, etc) with a limited lifetime(for example 1 minute), then send the value to the user's phone number via SMS.
2. you would have an endpoint that receives 6-digit strings as confirmSMS, which check the cache for that user and validate the input value with the existing value in the cache
3. if the validation result was ok, you should allow the user to change his/her password.